# Set a file wide breakpoint in gdb

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I'm trying to understand how a piece of code is working. I've enabled a breakpoint for a function, but it looks like it never gets hit. So, I'd like to break whenever ANY function within this class is invoked. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `rbreak regex` - for example:
`rbreak ^MyClass::`

Noteworthy fact:

> There is an implicit .* leading and trailing the regular expression you supply, so to match only functions that begin with foo, use ^foo.